# Gradient Descent Runtime Error

Tags: python, machine-learning, runtime-error, gradient

I have made a simple implementation of gradient descent for python and it works fine for most parameters but for certain parameters of learning rate and number of iterations it gives me a run time error.

RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in double_scalars

RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in double_scalars

Now I am assuming because it gets to a point where b and m values become too large to store in memory since there was an overflow error , is this assumption correct?

And how do I prevent program from crashing as exception handling in main program doesn't seem to work and can you think of a way without exception handling to prevent the error logically?

```
def compute_error(points,b,m):
    error = 0
    for i in range(len(points)):
        y = ponts[i][1]
        x = points[i][0]
        error +=  (y - (m*x + b))**2
    return error/len(points)

def gradient_runner(points,LR,num_iter,startB=0,startM=0):
    b = startB
    m = startM
    for i in range(num_iter):
        b,m = step_gradient(points,b,m,LR)
    return [b,m]

def step_gradient(points,b,m,LR):
    b_gradient = 0
    m_gradient = 0
    N = float(len(points))
    for i in range(len(points)):
        x = points[i][0]
        y = points[i][1]
        b_gradient+= (-2/N)*(y - ((m*x)+b))
        m_gradient+= (-2/N)*x*(y - ((m*x)+b))
##    print "Value for b_gradient",b_gradient
##    print "Value for b is ",b
##    print "Value for learning rate is ",LR
    new_b = b - (LR * b_gradient)
    new_m = m - (LR * m_gradient)
    return [new_b,new_m]    

import numpy as np
a = np.array([[1,1],[4,2],[6,3],[8,4],[11,5],[12,6],[13,7],[16,8]])

b,m=gradient_runner(a,0.0001,1000) # These parameters work
# b,m=gradient_runner(a,0.1,10000) #Program Crashes
yguesses = [m * i + b for i in a[:,0]]


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

guezz= yguesses

plt.scatter(a[:,0], a[:,1] ,color="green")
plt.plot(a[:,0],guezz,color="red")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is the the 'learning rate' LR (test this by only changing LR -- you will find that if you go low enough, the algorithm converges). With a too high value of `LR`, you take a too big step every time (imagine you 'jump over' the correct value at every step). There are ways to calculate what the maximum step size should be. Google around a little bit (e.g. "gradient descent step size").

However, as you note, if you get an overflow the result will most likely be erroneous. In Python you can [catch warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5644836/in-python-how-does-one-catch-warnings-as-if-they-were-exceptions), which you could use to tell the user that the result is wrong.

Comment: what options do we have if the learning rate has now become too low to avoid the overflow. in my case on setting a learning rate of 0.0001 makes the error go away but my gradient descent does not converge even for 2000 iterations.

Comment: @AbhyudayaSrinet Assuming your algorithm is correct, it might be the fact that your problem is not suitable for a plain gradient descent. You can try googling for stuff like "improving conditioning gradient descent".

Comment: Thanks. Turns out my implementation was incorrect. I was doing oneVsAll classification and using labels as my output values whereas I should've been using a class label vector (eg. [0,1,0,0]). This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40229964/1783688) helped me figure it out.